# Using a Trim function to remove extra characters not needed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to trim all of the cells that have data in column C to the left most 9 characters.

```
Sub TrimColumns()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

     If LastRow > Columns("B").Row Then
        Range("C2:C" & LastRow).LTrim(1,9) ' getting syntax error on this line 
     End If 
End Sub
```

`Range("C2:C" & LastRow).LTrim(1,9)` ' getting syntax error on this line

Comment: `LTrim` and `RTrim` are used to remove extra spaces at the beginning and end of a string. To get the leftmost or rightmost characters, you would use `Left` and `Right`

Comment: None of LTrim, RTrim, Left, or Right are methods of Range. They are are just functions that operate on strings. You will have to loop as Cyril's answer says, and for just 9 characters, the Left function is what you want.

Comment: Side note: always use fully qualified references (e.g.`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetName")`), as a `Range` indication *alone* refers automatically to the *currently selected* (work)sheet of all opened workbooks which might give unwanted results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Left`?

```
Cells(1,1).value = Left(Cells(1,1).value,9)
```

This would be looped down the range:

```
For i = 1 to LastRow Step 1
    Cells(i,3).value = Left(Cells(i,3).value,9)
Next i
```